# Maintain flex properties and fixed height while enabling scrolling for multiple items in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am very naive in developing react-native, please help me guys
firstly I code everything using flex properties, now i want to have multiple rendering of that item, so when the item is rendered 4 times it goes okay as because screen has space for 4 elements , but when i try to introduce 5th element as because screen was having space of 4 only so 5th element tries to adjust so I want to have my flex properties as it is and have a scroll-bar on them. For Example: i have 2 pages and each page contains 4 items and then pages are attached in a chain format i have scroll so that my flex properties are not disturbed and i have a scroll on that also.

In App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: '#e4e3e3' }]}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 / 5 }} >

        <Header name='Community' subHeading='Mobile App Developer Enthusiasts' />
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 4 / 5 }} >
        <CommunitiesList image={require("./assets/cover.png")} />
        <CommunitiesList image={require("./assets/cover.png")} />
        <CommunitiesList image={require("./assets/cover.png")} />
        <CommunitiesList image={require("./assets/cover.png")} />

      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

and in CommunitesList.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, Dimensions, Text } from "react-native";

const CommunitiesList = (props) => {
    const { image } = props
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 / 4, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end', }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', }}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.cover}
                    resizeMode="cover"
                    source={image}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={[styles.upperStyle, { marginTop: 7, backgroundColor: '#373eb2', height: 30, paddingRight: 6, paddingLeft: 6, position: 'absolute', justifyContent: 'center' }]}>
                <Text style={[{ color: 'white', padding: 2 }, styles.upperHeading]}>Data Science Enthusiasts</Text>
            </View>
        </View>

    );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    cover: {
        height: 132,
        width: '100%',
        position: "absolute",
    },
    upperHeading: {
        fontSize: 11,
        fontWeight: "700",
        fontFamily: "Calibri",

    },
    upperStyle: {
        borderBottomRightRadius: 12,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 12,
        backgroundColor: "#373eb2",
    }
});

export default CommunitiesList;
```

Can anybody please help, so that CommunityList can be rendered multiple times and without compromising the flex properties as i have for 4  and just having a scroll bar on them

Answer (score 0):

Flex is based on the parent container size, so this won't work - it'll always try to fit everything within the screen in this case. You'll have to calculate the dimensions manually:

```js
const { width: windowWidth } = Dimensions.get('window');
const itemWidth = windowWidth / 4;
```

If you need to calculate based on the parent size and not the whole window, use the onLayout prop on the parent view to get its size instead.

You'll also have to embed your components in a horizontal ScrollView:

```js
<ScrollView
  horizontal
  //...
>
  <Component />
  <Component />
  {/* ... */}
</ScrollView>
```